# Unable to connect Azure Logic App w/ System Assigned Managed Identity to Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity

I'm unsure what I'm missing here, but I cannot connect from Logic App to Azure SQL. Any help is appreciated.

**Steps performed:**

**1. Enabled `System Assigned Managed Identity` (SAMI) for the Logic App**

[image]

**2. Added the SAMI in a `Contributor` role for the SQL Server (its in another resource group)**

[image]

**3. Verified the SAMI role by clicking the `Azure role assignments` button**

[image]

**4. Added the SAMI in both the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles within the SQL Server itself using:**

```sql
CREATE USER [SAMI Name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [SAMI Name]
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [SAMI Name]
```

**5. Verified the internal roles were successful with:**

```sql
SELECT DP1.name AS DatabaseRoleName,
    isnull (DP2.name, 'No members') AS DatabaseUserName
FROM sys.database_role_members as DRM
RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals as DP1 
    ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals as DP2  
    ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id
WHERE DP1.type = 'R'
ORDER BY DP1.name;
```

**6. Add the `Get Rows (V2)` Azure SQL action in the Logic Apps Designer and create the connection**

[image]

**7. I can see that no server is found, so I enter the SQL server name as a custom value**

[image]

**8. After letting the Database Name load for a few mins, the action errors-out with:**

[image]

**Error text:**

```
Could not retrieve values. Error code: 'Unauthorized', Message: 'Credentials are missing or not valid.
     inner exception: The credentials provided for the SQL source are invalid. (Source at xxx.database.windows.net.)
clientRequestId: da158fe9-xxx'. More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is 'B1CBF136-xxx'.
```

**I have allowed Azure Services on the SQL Server, so I don't get why this is happening**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure of the cause of this, but I found that if you also enter the database name as a custom value then the connection works.

I experienced exactly the same symptoms as you. After manually entering the database name, the list of table names populates automatically.

I also found that it's not necessary to add the SAMI as a contributor to the SQL Server (at least, not for this particular workaround).

Before entering custom database name:
[image: Before entering custom database name]

After entering custom database name:
[image: After entering custom database name]

Comment: Thanks @Sean_McGrath. I needed someone to check my sanity. Yes, adding the DB Name (despite the error message) displays the Table names.

Comment: thanks heap, have been struggling with this issue, i think azure team should be  a bit proactive in such type of issues and at least should let people know these kind of things . I have created and deleted connnection and user at least 20 times today just to find this strange behaviour through your answer

Comment: Thank you.  I really hate Microsoft sometimes.  I did have to switch it Code View in order for it to let me save, but after that, all was good.